Regarding the asymptotic solution of the nonlinear ODE
I want to find the asymptotic solution to the non-linear ODE:
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2f}{dr^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{df}{dr}-\frac{n^2}{r^2}f-\frac{\lambda}{2}f(f^2-1)=0,
\end{equation}
with the boundary condition given by $f\to 1$ as $r\to\infty$ and $f$ is regular at $r=0$. The answer is given as
\begin{eqnarray}
f(r)&\sim& c_n r^n+\cdots,\quad r\to 0,\\
f(r)&\sim& 1-O(r^{-2}),\quad r\to\infty.\\
\end{eqnarray}
But I have no idea how to obtain the $r^{-2}$ behaviour for $r\to\infty$ case. Are there some general methods to do this?

Have you tried substituting $r={1 \over u}$?

Taking $f(r)=1+\frac C{r^2}+o\big(\frac 1{r^2}\big)$ and keeping the biggest (at $r\to\infty$) terms in the equation,
$$-\frac{n^2}{r^2}-\frac\lambda2\frac{2C}{r^2}=0,\Rightarrow,C=-\frac{n^2}\lambda$$

Taking $f(r) = 1$ the residual is $-\frac{n^2}{r^2}$ and $f(r)$ deserves a series expansion.

Proving that there is a series solution in negative powers of $r$ is easy. The difficult part is to show that it is an asymptotic expansion to an actual solution.

Is $\lambda>0$ or $\lambda<0$? This has a major impact on the stability of the fixed points $f=\pm1$ for $r\to \infty$
